# iOS 11 AppAuth handling redirect URI that redirects

Tags: oauth, ios11, google-oauth, appauth, sfauthenticationsession

When using [AppAuth (v 0.90.0)](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/tree/0.90.0) for Google OAuth authentication on my iOS app, specifically for iOS 11, the following happens:

1. Start Google authentication on the iOS client with a redirect URI `http://myproduct.com/oauth-redirect`. Because the client ID is that of a web application, I'm not able to specify a custom URL.
2. AppAuth starts a SFAuthenticationSession on the client, I'm prompted to allow sign-in. Select Continue. (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/0.90.0/Source/iOS/OIDAuthorizationUICoordinatorIOS.m#L91-L95)
3. `http://myproduct.com/oauth-redirect` redirects to a custom URL `myproduct://auth`, and SFAuthenticationSession completion block runs with a callback URL of `myproduct://auth`.
4. When AppAuth resumes the auth flow, it checks whether the original URL is the same as the callback URL from the previous step: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/0.90.0/Source/OIDAuthorizationService.m#L108-L110
5. Because `http://myproduct.com/oauth-redirect` and `myproduct://auth` are different, the flow stops.

Note that I'm using a web app clientID so that I can perform token exchange on the server side.

In the previous AppAuth version, this was possible because I was able to call `resumeAuthorizationFlowWithURL` directly with the updated URL.

Is there a way to support this use case without having to update AppAuth?

Comment: Hey the same issue here. Looks like noone answered so far. Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @Yang I created a PR to receive a mismatch error: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/pull/193 the maintainer marked it out of scope though. People are definitely running into this issue: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/232 Please bring it up in the thread so that we can address it properly! Thanks.